# Can't install kernel or configure dpkg

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg

I have always had problems with cleaning my kernels, but somehow I've always managed to do it. This time I don't ! I can't seem to remove any old kernel.

Now here is what happens when I try `sudo apt-get install 4.4.0-53-generic`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-tools-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
odermy@elda:~$ sudo apt-get install 4.4.0-53-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-tools-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
Note, selecting 'linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic' for regex '4.4.0-53-generic'
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-tools-4.4.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

or

I also tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
```

and `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And here is my `/etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I don't know how much of my quotes help but I've tried to post everything that was asked in similar cases.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my problem comes from my stupidity !

EDIT :

I forgot to post what happens when I try to remove older kernels, for instance `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-3.13.0-92-generic' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (4.4.0-53.74~14.04.1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-53-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-lts-xenial (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: run _sudo apt-get autoremove_ to if it gets rid of unused kernels so you can free up some space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your boot partition is full

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-53-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
```

Just free some space by first removing any old (unused) kernels and after that nstall the new one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to paste what happens when I try to do that, I'll edit my question right away

Comment: what's inside the `/boot` directory? Can you edit your question and add the output of `ls -l /boot` and `df -h` ?